# Changing the drop zone when drag & drop an icon on the desktop

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, drag-and-drop

I was wondering if it was possible to change the color of the drop zone when you are droping an icon/folder on your desktop. Most likely, it would be possible to change an HEX/RGBA value in the `gnome-shell.css` or in the `gtk.css` of the corresponding theme folder but I have difficulties finding the appropriate property.

If someone encountered this before and know how to proceed, that would be very much appreciated!

[image]